# Can i use a single NodeMCU IO pin to give select input to multiple 74HC157 ICs(2x1 mux ic)?

Tags: current, multiplexer, io

I have atleast '6' 74HC157 ICs in my design, with the select lines of all the 6 ICs tied up together(Fig1).I wish to give a logic high or logic low to the select line using just one NodeMCU IO pin. Can I do that?

I am doubtful as the maximum drain/sink current of a NodeMCU IO pin is 12mA and the datasheet of the IC says that Iol and Ioh for the IC is 5.2mA.

Hence if all 6 ICs were to be connected to a single IO pin, does that indicate a possibility of (5.2*6)mA of current sinking or sourcing from the NodeMCU IO pin?

[image: Fig1]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one NodeMCU output pin can drive multiple mux select inputs. You are mistakenly looking at mux output drive current.

Comment: Thanks, just needed to confirm this. Also the Iol and Ioh mentioned in the ICs datasheet is for its output pins right?